# Show current value and input value

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui

I created my simple range slider , here is my code

```js
$(".slider").slider({
  max: 120,
  min: 30
}).slider("pips");
```

```html
<div class="slider"></div>
```

I would know how to show above the slider a label with the current value and how to pass the current value to an input hidden form. what should I enter in value="" to get the current slider selected value ?

```html
<input type="hidden" value="" name="setting">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require hook to either the `slide` or `change` events of the slider. The arguments passed to the handler function for these events allow you to access the current value which lets you update the DOM as necessary:

```js
let $label = $('.slider-label');
let $value = $('.slider-value');

$(".slider").slider({
  max: 120,
  min: 30,
  slide: (e, ui) => {
    $label.text(ui.value);
    $value.val(ui.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-uto9mlQzrs59VwILcLiRYeLKPPbS/bT71da/OEBYEwcdNUk8jYIy+D176RYoop1Da+f9mvkYrmj5MCLZWEtQuA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-aOG0c6nPNzGk+5zjwyJaoRUgCdOrfSDhmMID2u4+OIslr0GjpLKo7Xm0Ao3xmpM4T8AmIouRkqwj1nrdVsLKEQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<p class="slider-label">30</p>
<input type="text" class="slider-value" value="30" name="setting" />
<div class="slider"></div>
```

Also note that `slider('pips')` is not a valid invocation for the jQueryUI slider plugin and will be causing an error. You should remove that line.